# Get all next records respective to fetched ones in Room database?

Tags: sql, android-room

I tried something which is syntactically incorrect else would have solved it easily:

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM table1 WHERE id > IN (ids)
method(List<Integer> ids)
```

What I'm doing right now:

Query 1:
List obtained:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE someRecord=1;
List<Integer> integers;
```

Query 2:
Using a for loop to iterate through list and save next record id into a list:

```
List<Integers> newIds=new ArrayList();

    for(Integer i:integers){

    newIds.add(SELECT MIN(id) FROM table1 WHERE id >i);


    }
```

Query 3:
Fetching all next records:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (newIds);
getIds(List<Integer> newIds)
```

How do I use MIN(id) or something else with a list of ids (ids > IN (2,3,4)) so the query returns all the next records, respective to individual records?

Update: (Does not work as expected)

The below query works to fetch all next records if anyone else is looking but no way to use MIN(id) with List exists in Room DB for now.

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id > (SELECT table1.id FROM table1 WHERE id IN (:integer_ids))
getNextRecordIds(List<Integer> integer_ids)
```

Comment: so you're asking for a sql-only approach?

Comment: @curiosa It should be possible as per my understanding to do it in a single query. The MIN(id) has to take in a List<Integer> for that and I would like to know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every `id` in the list exists in the table...

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MIN(lookup.id)
       FROM table1 AS lookup
      WHERE lookup.id > table1.id
    )
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    id IN (:integer_ids)
```

If the `id` list can include values Not in the table, insert the list in to a temporary table first...

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MIN(lookup.id)
       FROM table1 AS lookup
      WHERE lookup.id > list.id
    )
FROM
    #temporaryTable AS list
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would be helpful but consider next query to replace Query1-Query3 from your post (`id` parameter in the method below is parameter from your Query1):

```
@Query("WITH result2 AS " +
            "(SELECT min(id) AS idNext FROM table1 JOIN (SELECT id AS idPrev FROM table1 WHERE someRecord = :id) AS result1 ON table1.id > result1.idPrev GROUP BY result1.idPrev) " +
            "SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN result2 ON table1.id=result2.idNext")
List<Table1> getNextRecords(Int id)
```